# Strange if-statement evaluation behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

My javascript is behaving very strange!

I have a input field in my html file. This input field is read by javascript in the following way:

```
var bscore = $("#bscore").val();
```

Then i want to show an alert if the input is below a certain input

```
if(bscore<"913"){
    document.getElementById("bscorealert").style.display="block";
};
```

This works fine. So when the number is above 913 it should not show. Only javascript is behaving very strange, when the number in the bscore input field is above 999 (so 1000 and higher) the if statement is triggered and the alert is shown.

How is this possible?

Comment: You're comparing two strings presumably, rather than two integers.

Comment: Do not use quotes to compare numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible because you are comparing strings, not integers. String comparison is lexicographical, so `"9" > "10"` and so on.

You will want to convert before comparing with `Number(strValue)` or with the unary operator `+`:

```
var bscore = +$("#bscore").val();    // + prefix converts to number
if (bscore < 913) ...                // no quotes around 913!
```

Comment: +1 for the "prefix converter" stuff. Didn't knew that

Comment: @Kazzkiq: That's precisely why you might want to use `Number(whatever)` instead -- it's way more self-explanatory. ;-)

Comment: I didn't need to convert the input to a number, but the removal of the quotes did the trick! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Two notes: When converting user input (as from an input field), it's best to use `parseInt` and specify the radix, e.g. `var bscore = parseInt($("#bscore").val(), 10);`. 2. If you don't feel like doing that, and you use a number for one of the operands, the first thing the JavaScript engine will try to do is convert the other operand to a number. So `if ($("#bscore").val() < 913)` will compare numerically.

Comment: @NiekBakermans: That's because when comparing a string to a number, the engine will auto-convert the string to a number. Still best to use `parseInt` on end-user input, though.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added this to my code, don't need it on my own machine (safari), but the finished product will be used on IE8. So better be safe than sorry with that browser.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I consciously decided against `parseInt` because that would "validate" input such as "10asdfasdf". Converting both operands explicitly is indeed not required, but I prefer it because the code reads closer to what it does.

Comment: @Jon: Ah, yes, you do need to handle that (surprising) behavior of `parseInt`.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to compare 2 strings, which uses the alphabetical comparison. If you enter a value between 9130 and 9999 in the field, you'll notice that the messagebox doesn't show as well.

You'll have to do a parseInt to compare numerical values.